# was the octet rule disproven?

Tags: orbitals

so according to my understanding orbitals can hold s can hold 2 electrons and p can hold 8 electron d hold 18 and f can hold 32. wouldn't this violate the octet rule? which say only the first shell can hold 2 electrons and the rest of the shells 8. im also confused why some websites says that each orbital has 2 electrons, s has 1 orbital  (2 electrons) p has 3 orbitals (6 electrons) d has 5 (10 electrons) and f has 7 orbits ( 14 electrons)

im so confused guys plz help me as simple as possible

Comment: The octet uses s and p orbitals of the outer shell: 2 + 6 = 8. In the fourth period, you are filling 4s, 3d and 4p; that's why there are 18 elements in the fourth period. See https://madoverchemistry.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/4112.jpg?w=1680

Comment: As with many things in chemistry, it isn't so much a Rule as a Suggestion. It helps explain some things, but then it gets complicated really fast.

Answer (score 3):

The octet rule has no theoretical basis. It has been observed to work quite often. But that is all we could say. It cannot be proven. The octet rule works nearly perfectly in organic chemistry,

There are many examples where this rule is not verified. For example the Boron hydrides, the simplest being $B_2H_6$. This compound is commercial, but it does not follow the octet rule. Another example is the familiar molecule of Oxygen $O_2$, which has no double bond as often given in elementary chemistry courses. Other examples : $PCl_5, SF_6$. Another simple example is Nitrogen oxide $NO$. And a lot of compounds made with metals from the transition range.

Comment: +1 Good point about organic chemistry.

Comment: Even in organic chemistry there are some boners.  Try to apply it to the [cyclopropenyl](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclopropenium_ion) ring system.  The electron count that gives a stable structure is two less than what would satisfy the octet rule.

Answer (score 1):

The [octet rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_rule) is basically a rule for low atomic number elements like carbon and some other specific elements like the alkali metals and the halide anions. It is typically coupled with the [Lewis Dot notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_structure) as a first example of chemical bonding. However there are [other forms of bonding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_rule#Exceptions) that involve more than just the $s$ and $p$ electrons.

Comment: And even with just $s$ and $p$, molecular orbital structure can override the octet rule.