# Why dosen't NO₂ form according to the octet rule?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, resonance, lewis-structure

Supposedly every atom that is in the second period of the periodic table has to obey the octet rule; this means that they have to be surrounded by 8 electrons (or so I was taught). Studying resonance in an exercise, they showed how nitrogen as NO₂ can form 5 bonds, which would mean that NO₂ does not behave according to the rule previously mentioned. I am at a loss; any help would be great.

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/129489/50406)

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9448/structure-of-no2-compound

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't unstable odd electron species dimerize so that they become stable?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20086/why-dont-unstable-odd-electron-species-dimerize-so-that-they-become-stable)

Comment: Capitalization can be important - your question title is asking about the diatomic Nobelium molecule, and I have no clue if that is even a thing...

Comment: Because not everything has to.

Answer (score 3):

No atom has to obey the octet rule. It is a rule. It has no theoretical justification. It works often. But that's all that could be stated. And a lot of compounds are known that do not follow this rule like $O_2, NO, B_2H_6$, etc. And Nitrogen does not form 5 bonds. It cannot. $4$ bonds is the maximum for atoms of the second period (Li, Be, B, C, N, O, F).